# sudo service nginx reload wrong path?

Tags: nginx, configuration, path

here's the problem I face.

after `sudo service nginx reload`

I saw these messages

[image]

As you see, the configuration file path is

```
/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

But I expect it to be

```
/etc/nginx/site-enabled/my_app.conf
```

how should I change the nginx config path?

[updated] Here's the message of nginx -V
  [image]

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -V` to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani, ok, I've just updated the post.

Comment: `nginx.conf` is the main configuration file. Other files (such as `sites-enabled/*`) are pulled into it using `include` statements. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to see the full configuration (which hopefully includes `my_app.conf`).

Comment: What @RichardSmith mentions is true. As long as you are not worried about the config to come from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and it loaded the `my_app.conf` this should not be an issue